# extracting orientation from Stage odometry using quaternions

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone.

i'm writing a subscriber of a nav_msgs/Odometry topic where Stages writes its own messages.
I can easily get x,y position of robot, while for its orientation i should elaborate quaternion included in each message.
I know, from other tutorials, that i could solve problem by using

```
tf::getYaw(robot_pose.orientation)
```

where robot_pose.orientation is the quaternion contained in every generic message received.
To make this work, i should add at the beginning of file

```
#include "tf/transform_listener"
```

but no header and no file is found with such name at compiling time. By using command

```
rospack find tf
```

i realized that i have tf package installed. I even built it through command rosmake.
can you help me?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48479/extracting-orientation-from-stage-odometry-using-quaternions/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure your `manifest.xml` has the dependency to the `tf` package:

```
<depend package="tf"/>
```

Also, you might be missing the **.h** in your include:

```
#include "tf/transform_listener.h"
```

The `getYaw` method however is defined somewhere else, so I would use

```
#include "tf/transform_datatypes.h"
```

See [tf API](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/namespacetf.html#33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b)

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2